# Счетчик для теста

Tags: javascript, input, count

Задача написать тест. Вопросы на три варианта ответа и в зависимости от выбранных ответов, соответственно три вывода.

Счетчик ответов работает некорректно.. Первый вопрос дает правильное значение, а последующие по разному.

**В чем моя ошибка?**

Пробовал с текущей страницы таким образом результат брать, не помогло.

```
var pageN = $ ('.page' + n);
switch ($( 'pageN input[name]:checked' ).val())
```

```js
var n = 1;
var b = 0,
  m = 0,
  d = 0;

$('#start-test').click(function() {
  $('.page').css("display", "none");
  $('.page1').css("display", "block");
});

$('.arrow-right').click(function() {
  $('.page' + n).css("display", "none");
  onChecked();
  n++;
  $('.page' + n).css("display", "block");

  switch ($("input[name]:checked").val()) {
    case 'B':
      alert('Бизнес');
      b++;
      break;
    case 'D':
      alert('Дизайн');
      d++;
      break;
    case 'M':
      alert('Медиа');
      m++;
      break;
  }

  function onChecked() {
    console.log($("input:radio:checked").val());
  }

  console.log(b, m, d);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div class="page1">
  <p class="orange-text">Вопрос 1</p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="D" name="answer1">Ответ Д</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="B" name="answer1">Ответ Б</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="M" name="answer1">Ответ М</label>
  <img class="arrow-left-off" src="img/arr/back.png" alt="Назад">
  <img class="arrow-right" src="img/arr/next.png" alt="Вперед">
</div>

<div class="page2">
  <p class="orange-text">Вопрос 2</p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="B" name="answer2">Ответ Б</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="M" name="answer2">Ответ М</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="D" name="answer2">Ответ Д</label>
  <img class="arrow-left" src="img/arr/back.png" alt="Назад">
  <img class="arrow-right" src="img/arr/next.png" alt="Вперед">
</div>

<div class="page3">
  <p class="orange-text">Вопрос 3</p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="B" name="answer3">Ответ Б</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="M" name="answer3">Ответ М</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="D" name="answer3">Ответ Д</label>
  <img class="arrow-left" src="img/arr/back.png" alt="Назад">
  <img class="arrow-right" src="img/arr/next.png" alt="Вперед">
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы могли бы добавить свой html и обернуть все в секцию `Фрагмент кода`. Тогда Ваш вопрос выглядел бы нагляднее и ответ на него дадут быстрее.

Comment: Я бы сказал так, вы кликаете на разные блоки, а данные берете всегда из первой формы.

Comment: Не пойму принцип. Он первые три значения записывает ответ на первый вопрос, а следующие значения уже берет другие [ссылка](http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/05/e33cf7799a96b50c34f848bada1ae672.png)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как отметил @ВасилийБарбашев, хотя Вы и прячете/показываете разные фрагменты html, значение `$("input[name]:checked").val()` всегда берется из первого `"input[name]:checked"` на странице.

Ограничьте выборку инпутов родителем кнопки:

```
switch ($(this).parent().find("input[name]:checked").val()) {
```

Или Ваш вариант (исправлен):

```
var pageN = '.page' + n;
switch ($(pageN + ' input[name]:checked').val()) {
```

но тут надо аккуратно поддерживать текущее значение `n`.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Чуть-чуть меня поправили и все заработало))